# faulty touch screen/android touchpad for same device

Tags: android, touch, touchpad

I have an android phone with a small rectangle area of the touch screen not working(red rectangle in the image).

[faulty touch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpUpH.jpg)

[see video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8eZ_Cl8xP9ASnVTRzZxbWtyMnc)

The question is: Is there a way to tap on the faulty area using the other working area as 80%+ of touch is all right? I think of a virtual touchpad .I couldn't find anything after extensive searching. 
Basically I'm looking for a way to manipulate the mouse in Android. When you plug in an external mouse to the USB, a pointer comes up which can be used instead of touch input and gives you more precision/mouseover control.

I was looking for an app to control this mouse pointer programmatically -i.e a virtual touchpad to control the same android device.All the apps i have searched ,control either windows/linux PC or another android device